# How to get value from an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var schema = {
    title: {
        label: 'xxxx', className: 'title'
    },     
    body: [
        //Q1
        {label: '1. x2', tag: 'radio',
        data1 : [
            {'value': '1', 'label': 'y'},
            {'value': '2', 'label': 'n'},
        ],   
    },
    ]
 }
```

Here is the code. I want to get 'value' from 'data1', how can i achieve it.

schema['body'][0]['data1'][1].value
this works. thx.

Comment: try `schema.body[0].data1[0].value`

Comment: show the Efforts that you have tried yet??

Answer (score 0):

`schema['body'][0]['data1'][0].value` and

```
schema['body'][0]['data1'][1].value
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use like this `schema.body[0].data1.map(a => a.value)` .They [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is iterate the all value of the `data1` array

```js
var schema = {
  title: {
    label: 'xxxx',
    className: 'title'
  },
  body: [
    //Q1
    {
      label: '1. x2',
      tag: 'radio',
      data1: [{
          'value': '1',
          'label': 'y'
        },
        {
          'value': '2',
          'label': 'n'
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}

console.log(schema.body[0].data1.map(a => a.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the answer to your homework, but here is an overly complicated way of doing it:

```
function getValue(obj, props){
    if(!props.length)   return [obj];
    if(typeof obj !== "object") return [];
    if(!obj)    return [];

    var values = [];
    for(var key in obj){
        var prop = props.slice();
        if(key === props[0]){
            prop.shift();
        }
        values = values.concat(getValue(obj[key], prop));
    }
    return values;
}

getValue(schema, ["data1", "value"]);    // ["1", "2"]
```

Extra credit if you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps it should be helpful

```
1. First you need to change object into string
2. Use JSON.parse to get json object
3. From json object you can access any items like below sample
```

sample code:

```
var text = '{"title":{"label":"xxxx","className":"title"},"body":[{"label":"1. x2","tag":"radio","data1":[{"value":"1","label":"y"},{"value":"2","label":"n"}]}]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(obj.body[0].data1[0].label);
```

Here is the working sample code : http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/5389/